# Converting map consisting of multiple DXF layers to shape in QGIS 3.10 LTR

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, dxf

I'd like to develop a workflow for the following issue:
There is a map in DXF format which consists of multiple (924) layers. All together they show a complex city map.
Using the Import/Export function works fine for me. Is there a workflow to import the DXF files and build a single vector layer containing all the DXF layers. A shapefile would be fine for me.

Comment: Shapefile can hold only one layer. Do you have a plan about how to harmonize the 924 layers so that they will all have similar type of geometries and same attribute schema?

Answer (score 1):

Install the AnotherDXFImporter plug-in for Qgis (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/). This plug-in let you import DXF file and save it as shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

You may drag & drop `dxf` files into QGIS directly. Upon import you may in/exclude single layers of the `dxf`, but you can also choose to import all. Then you can use the tool `merge vector layers` and export everything as a single shapefile/geopackage. When done in an otherwise empty QGIS project, this procedure is rather fast, since you may choose all files during both import and export.